# ListWheelScrollView freezes

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget, scrollview

I am using ListWheelScrollView to display my Data...

unfortunetly the ListWheelScrollView freezes and does not respond if I scroll slowly....

```
ListWheelScrollView(
                              diameterRatio: 5,
                              itemExtent: 250,
                              children: [
                                ...controller.events.map((event) {
                                  return EasyContainer(
                                    margin: 10,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                                    borderColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    borderStyle: BorderStyle.solid,
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderRadius: 10,
                                    showBorder: true,
                                    onTap: () => Get.to(
                                        () => const EventDetailsScreen()),
                                    //TODO: pass Arguments of Event to new Screen
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              const Icon(Icons.star,
                                                  color: Colors.yellow),
                                              const Expanded(
                                                  child: SizedBox()),
                                              Container(
                                                child: Text(
                                                    event.eventType!.tr,
...
```

Any Ideas why it is so slowly, buggy or doesn´t work...

Comment: What's controller here?

Comment: It´s a GetXController...just holds the data when fetched.

Comment: Try prepopulating the list and passing that list to the list when scroll view